# How to submit parallel job steps with SLURM?

Tags: slurm, sbatch

I have the following SLURM job script named `gzip2zipslurm.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --mem 70G
#SBATCH --ntasks 4
echo "Task 1"
srun -n1 java -Xmx10g -jar tar2zip-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar articles.A-B.xml.tar.gz  &
echo "Task 2"
srun -n1 java -Xmx10g -jar tar2zip-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar articles.C-H.xml.tar.gz  &
echo "Task 3"
srun -n1 java -Xmx10g -jar tar2zip-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar articles.I-N.xml.tar.gz  &
echo "Task 4"
srun -n1 java -Xmx10g -jar tar2zip-1.0.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar articles.O-Z.xml.tar.gz  &
echo "Waiting for job steps to end"
wait
echo "Script complete"
```

I submit it to SLURM by `sbatch gzip2zipslurm.sh`.
When I do, the output of the SLURM log file is

```
Task 1
Task 2
Task 3
Task 4
Waiting for job steps to end
```

The `tar2zip` program reads the given `tar.gz` file an re-packages it as a `ZIP` file.

The Problem: Only one CPU (out of 16 available on an idle node) is doing any work. With `top` I can see that all in all 5 `srun` commands have been started (4 for my tasks and 1 implicit for the sbatch job, I guess) but there is only one Java process. I can also see it on the files being worked on, only one is written.

How do I manage that all 4 tasks are actually executed in parallel?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue might be with the memory reservation. In the submission script, you set `--mem=70GB`, that is the global memory usage of the job.

When `srun` is used within a submission script, it inherits parameters from `sbatch`, including the `--mem=70GB`. So you actually implicitly run the following.

```
srun --mem 70G -n1 java -Xmx10g -jar ...
```

Try explicitly stating the memory to 70GB/4 with:

```
srun --mem 17G -n1 java -Xmx10g -jar ...
```

Also, as per the documentation, you should use `--exclusive` with `srun` in such a context.

```
srun --exclusive --mem 17G -n1 java -Xmx10g -jar ...
```

> This option can also be used when initiating more than one job step
>   within an existing resource allocation, where you want separate
>   processors to be dedicated to each job step. If sufficient processors
>   are not available to initiate the job step, it will be deferred. This
>   can be thought of as providing a mechanism for resource management to
>   the job within it's allocation.

Comment: Ah of course. Kind of stupid of me. Still struggeling a bit with "jobs", "steps" and "tasks" I guess ;-) Thank you very much. I also read about the `--exclusive` switch. I had left it out to avoid more complexity. But now I use it as you recommended and it' working fine. Thank you!